# Creating sample space in R

Tags: r

I'm taking this "Basic Statistics" course in Coursera and it has some practical exercises in R. Sadly, they are very poorly explained and give very little feedback when not correct.

> DESCRIPTION: You have a bag containing three A and two E scrabble
>   letters. You consider the sample space of drawing three letters from
>   the bag without replacing them (i.e. each trial is dependent).
>
> In your script, make a vector called "samplespace" containing each
>   value of the sample space as a string.

What I have tried so far:

```
samplespace <- c(rep("A",3), rep("E",2))
samplespace <- c("A","A","A","E","E")
```

For both of them I get the following feedback:

> You haven't created x correctly.

So, I pretty much don't know what to do. Can anyone help?

Comment: I found the correct answer:
samplespace <- c("AAA", "AAE", "AEE", "EAA", "EEA", "AEA", "EAE")

Answer (score 1):

samplespace <- c("AAA", "AAE", "AEE", "AEA", "EAE", "EEA", "EAA")

I just shorthanded it on paper and then typed it all in. Since we haven't been given any formulas in the lesson pertaining to this yet.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I am not sure is an answer, surely the purpose of this is to generate the sample space by code rather than manually typing out the result.

Comment: Thank you Peter, still a newbie but looking forward to the journey. I agree that's what I thought the purpose would be as well. This question is through data camp. they have not taught us how to create a sample space yet and have not provided the necessary formulas yet. The answer I posted above worked, the answer the other user posted above mine did not work as acceptable. It's kind of funny but I think they're just trying to get us more comfortable in r at the moment and will introduce more complex functions fro creating sample space soon.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, the following will do it.

```
s <- c(rep("A",3), rep("E",2))

samplespace <- unique(apply(combn(s, 3), 2, paste0, collapse = ""))
samplespace 
[1] "AAA" "AAE" "AEE"
```